# How to fix the error in the color_post function in this code?

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop, floor

I have this data:

```
lon = [121,1.212500000000000e+02,1.215000000000000e+02,1.217500000000000e+02,122];
lat = [10,10.250000000000000,10.500000000000000,10.750000000000000,11];
bdlvl = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

I want to use the function `color_post` for this data. However, I am encountering some errors. For instance when I input `color_post(lon, lat, bdlvl, [])` it sends back an error indicating "*Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 1*".

Also there is an error with this certain line:

```
item=floor((1+var(ibb2(i),1)-a)/(b-a)*63);
```

Here's the code:

```
function color_post(lon,lat,var,limit)
    % mapping z values with gradient of colors
    % make sure you have set your projection area already
    m=length(var);
    hold on 
    
    load('C:\Users\Pia\Downloads\scripts\MyRainbowCmap.mat')
    cmap=mycmap;
    
    if isempty(limit)==1;
        a = min(var); b = max(var);
    else
        a = limit(1); b=limit(2);
    end
    
    caxis([a b]);
    hold on
    
    var(imag(var) ~= 0) = NaN;
    ibb2 = find(isfinite(var));
    %for i=length(ibb2):-1:1;
    for i=1:length(ibb2);
        item=floor((1+var(ibb2(i),1)-a)/(b-a)*63);
        if(item<1)
            item=1;
        end
        if(item>64)
           item=64;
        end
        m_plot(lon(ibb2(i)),lat(ibb2(i)),'o','color',cmap(item,:),'markerfacecolor',cmap(item,:),'MarkerSize',7);   
    end
    fig=gcf; set(fig,'Colormap',mycmap);
    %h=colorbar;
```

I tried changing the `for i=1:length(ibb2);` into  `for i=0:length(ibb2);`. I expect that this function will help me to classify my bed level values according to colors.

Hope you could help me!

Comment: What is in `MyRainbowCmap.mat` file. Are there variable in side it or is it some sort of dataset? And what version of matlab are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change  `var(ibb2(i), 1)` to `var(1, ibb2(i))`;

In the for loop at `item=floor((1+var(ibb2(i),1)-a)/(b-a)*63);`, you are accessing the each elements of `var` but you are iterating over its rows and fixed the column `var(ibb2(i), 1)`.

`var` has 1 row and 5 columns. You have to iterate over the coulmns while keeping the row constant like this `var(1, ibb2(i))`. The final equation will be

```
item=floor((1+var(1, ibb2(i))-a)/(b-a)*63);
```

Hope that helps